# How to create treeview in silverlight data grid?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

May i know how to add treeview within data grid.
I would like to create a treeview in one column and check box in another column.

something like this https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2e36821a-dacd-45a4-984a-47475ef242a0/showImage/127786

but dont want to use third party controls.

THank you

Comment: I used https://multicolumntreelist.codeplex.com/ for this. Still a third-party control, but fairly simple and free (GPLv2).

Answer (score 0):

Just define your `DataGrid` columns using `DataGridTemplateColumn`, like this:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding myDgItemsSource}">
  <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="My TreeView">
      <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding dgListPropertyForTreeViewList}" ItemTemplate="    {StaticResource TemplateForMyTreeViewItems}">
          </sdk:TreeView>
        </DataTemplate>
      </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="My Checkbox">
      <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding propertyOnDgList, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```